# What's the best way to run a long script without the SSH client crashing?

Tags: opensuse, job-control, batch-jobs

I'm on OpenSUSE 12.1, so no tmux, and we're not allowed to install anything - wget is too old to download a binary as well. Often I and other users have to run long scripts that take several hours, and our SSH client will crash in the middle. I'm aware that this is a bad practice but my opinion isn't valued.

What's a good way to "schedule" or somehow run these long scripts without the danger of them ending if the client crashes? Cron jobs maybe?

Comment: Can you enable SSH keepalive? That might help. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084288/keep-ssh-session-alive

Comment: I've worked at places like this and they are afraid of upgrading to current releases or their license costs increase too much so I just tell them in emails and cc myself so they see I'm informing them of the security weaknesses and they may be legally liable if they are unable to patch and secure it. But I mention free alternatives like CentOS, Oracle Linux, Debian, etc. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be screen, if it is available. (You mentioned tmux, but not screen)

Another option would be to run the script with "nohup" which will disassociate it from your shell. You would then need to use its pid to monitor it. Redirecting the output to files would also be recommended.

Answer (score 2):

cron jobs are useful if you have a repeated job. For one shot runs, you can use `at` as well; it takes a time specification, and a list of jobs on `STDIN`

```
$ at now+1
your job here
^D
```

This would run your job one minute from now.